# Bathroom tub leaking

Tags: bathroom, leak

Is there a way to difinitively determine if a tub is leaking? My tub has a small crack in it but I thought it was cosmetic. Earlier today after my son took a bath i noticed a drip in the basement a few feet from where the tub sits. I pulled the tile an it kinda looks like it might have just been from him splashing etc but I want to make sure before I finish the floor 
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to fill the tub with water and check for leaks:

1. Wait until the surrounding area is completely dry
2. Fill tub full of water and mark water level
3. Let the water stand for a couple hours
4. Check water level for any change and look for any signs of moisture around/under tub

On an aside, that crack looks a bit more then just cosmetic and will most likely get worse over time. If you're unable to replace the tub now, you can look for a local company that repairs fibreglass tubs. They should be able to advise you if it's repairable or not.